# ListActivity Intents

Tags: android

I currently have a ListActivity and I am looking to start a new activity based on the selection in the list. Based upon Intents and Extras, how can I make this possible? Here is my code so far:

```
package com.fragile.honbook;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class GuideSelection extends ListActivity{

private TextView selection;

private static final String[] heroes={ "Agility", "Intelligence",
    "Strength"};

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.heroselect);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row, R.id.label,
            heroes));

    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.select);
}
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
                                int position, long id){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, position, long id){
  Intent intent = new Intent(GuideSelection.this, NewActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("hero", heroes[position]);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

***Update (with different activities per list item):***

```
final Map<String, Class> activities = new HashMap<String, Class>();

{
   activities.put("agility", AgilityActivity.class);
   activities.put("intelligence", IntelligenceActivity.class);
   // add more here
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, position, long id){
  Intent intent = new Intent(GuideSelection.this, activities.get(heroes[position]));
  intent.putExtra("hero", heroes[position]);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: My only question to this would be, if I have multiple activities, how does this pick any other activity than "NewActivity".

Comment: then you have to make a test base on the list item and then call intent of the activity which you need

Comment: I have changed my best vote to this new update, thank you sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this
If you want to call an activity called NewActivity after clicking the list item with sending data as extra you can do this

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id){

    Intent intent = new Intent(GuidSelection.this, NewActivity.Class());
    intent.putExtra("DATA",heroes[position]);
    GuideSelection.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(position==1){
       //First item clicked.
       Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent));
    } 
// handle else ifs
}
```

This is just an idea. You may wish to improvise this to too much of if elses.